# SwiftUI - Limit Decimal Places for Slider

Tags: swift, swiftui, slider

I am trying to implement a slider in my app but it's too accurate:

[image: slider screenshot]

I want the steps to instead increment by "0.1" only. How can I do that? this is my current implementation:

```
            @State private var introTextBackgroundColor = Color.white
            @State private var introTextBackgroundOpacity = 0.3

            HStack {
                Text("Opacity")
                Text(self.introTextBackgroundOpacity.description)
            }
            Slider(value: self.$introTextBackgroundOpacity, in: 0.0...1.0)
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/slider/init(value:in:step:label:oneditingchanged:) There is a `step` parameter.

Comment: Over the word `Slider` in Xcode, press Option+click on it. You'll see the documentation and how to use the parameter "step".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `step` parameter:

```
Slider(value: self.$introTextBackgroundOpacity, in: 0.0...1.0, step: 0.1)
```